# Can I reflect on NgRx action payloads?

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I'd like to be able to create a common library in Angular that can be fed any array of NgRx actions (or perhaps Action Types?) and generate a UX to enter the properties of the "props" for each action.

I've been trying to figure out how to reflect over the functions returned from createAction, but I haven't figure out how or even if it can be done yet.

So, if my action looks like this...

```
export const membersLoaded = createAction('[MemberEffects] Members Loaded', props<{members: IMember[]}>());
```

I'd like to know that the payload has a members property and that members property is an array of IMember.

Is it possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't possible.
We don't have those types at runtime, the types are only there during our development process and at compile time.

Comment: I think you're right. What we're doing at the moment is creating an object, an instance of a class, and trolling through it's properties to get their types. If someone selects "memberCreate", we have a switch statement that creates an empty Member, which we pass to our form builder function to build the UX.  It's not the best, but it's working so far.